# Form posting input values updated in jquery to a controller in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel-5

Currently, I'm working on a Laravel form and I have to pass some values to a database.  I'm doing this through the traditional way of getting my values and sending them via a request in my controller.

In my form, I have some drop downs that are populated by an ajax request via jquery.  My ajax request updates the values in the drop down and they are visible to the user to select.

Here is one of the lis

```
<li value="25" data-cost="94.00"><span>25</span></li>
```

Once the li is selected to pass the data to Laravel I have jquery create a hidden input.

```
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="50">
```

Then in my laravel controller I do this:

```
$productOrderDetails->quantity = $request->input('quantity');
```

My expected behavior is for my controller to receive the "value" of whatever the input field is.  However, I get null no value is passed over.
I suspect it would be because the input is created in the DOM by jquery but wouldn't this be the same as a user typing something into an input box?  I realize there are client side and server side based upon the responses to some similar questions.  Any direction would be appreciated, thank you!

UPDATE:
This item is in the DOM

```
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="100">
```

When I submit my form, the DD results is this:

```
 array:3 [▼
  "_token" => "LlE3YWnLZNLNWgGyXUY8E0GqSXz8cpUleIBSwsD5"
  "product" => "Postcards"
  "job_name" => "Testing"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input is present in the form on the page, then it should get submitted when the form is submitted even if it was added using JS on the client.

Verify that the input is actually in the form as you expect using your devtools DOM inspector.

You could also try a dd($request->all()) to see all of what is getting sent to your controller.

Comment: Hi @Peter I updated the question with the value of the DD along with an input that is in the DOM.  One thing that input is inside a span would that make a difference?

Comment: @FabricioG Is the hidden input field getting added within the <form> tags on the page? Is the form getting submitted by clicking a submit button or via JS?

Comment: yes it is with in the form tags.  It is submitted when user clicks on "Add to Cart" which is a submit button. @Peter

Comment: You could try looking at the request on the Network tab in Chrome devtools. You should be able to see what data is sent with the post request by looking at the Headers section. Check to see if your hidden input data is getting included in the request.

Comment: The problem is that the input tag is in a ul so it will not receive it since it's not a form tag.  I tested the same input outside of the ul tag and it worked.  @Peter

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! In the future, if you post more of your code then it will be easier to help you find the problem.